Problem with the ubuntu dock
I have enabled the gnome dock from the gnome-extensions app, but it keeps appearing in weird places and sometimes two dock appear on top of each other[enter image description here][1]

You didn't post the picture. Please edit to post it again.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
